# MomentJS - How to get last day of previous month from date?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I'm trying to get last day of the previous month using:

```
 var dateFrom = moment(dateFrom).subtract(1, 'months').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

Where:

```
dateFrom = 2014-11-30
```

But after using

```
subtract(1, 'months')
```

it returns date

```
DATE_FROM: "2014-10-30"
```

But last day of the 10'th month is 31.

How can I solve i please?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

Simply add a `endOf('month')` to your calls:

`var dateFrom = moment(dateFrom).subtract(1,'months').endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');`

http://jsfiddle.net/r42jg/327/

Comment: For more information check the docs for [`#endOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/end-of/). And also check out its counterpart [`#startOf`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/start-of/).

Comment: Other way var dateFrom = moment(dateFrom).startOf('month').subtract(1,'days'); ;-)

Comment: You might wanna do this: `moment(dateFrom).subtract(1, 'month').daysInMonth('D')`

Answer (score 10):

An even easier solution would be to use `moment.date(0)`. the `.date()` function takes the 1 to n day of the current month, however, passing a zero or negative number will yield a dates in the previous month.

For example if current date is February 3rd:

```js
var _date = moment(); // 2018-02-03 (current day)
var _date2 = moment().date(0) // 2018-01-31 (start of current month minus 1 day)
var _date3 = moment().date(4) // 2018-02-04 (4th day of current month)
var _date4 = moment().date(-4) // 2018-01-27 (start of current month minus 5 days)

console.log(_date.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log(_date2.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log(_date3.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log(_date4.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.20.1/moment.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 8):

Last month's First date and last month's last date from the current date basis. The Format of the date changes depending upon. (DD-MM-YYYY)

```
console.log("last month first date");
   const lastmonthlastdate=moment().subtract(1, 'months').startOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
console.log(lastmonthlastdate);

console.log("lastmonth last date");
   const lastmonthfirstdate=moment().subtract(1, 'months').endOf('month').format('DD-MM-YYYY')
console.log(lastmonthfirstdate);
```

Comment: Not sure what this answer is adding to the one answered 5 years sooner. Not to mention, the OP wanted to count from a specific date, not the current date, and wanted the output in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Answer (score 4):

```
moment().subtract(1, 'months').endOf('month').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first day of the month then subtract 1 day to get the last day of the previous month.

```
const monthyear = moment().format('YYYY-MM')
const firstDay = moment(monthyear + "-01").format("YYYY-MM-DD");
// Subtract 1 day to get the end of the previous month
const dateTo = moment(firstDay).subtract('1', 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```